# Android SQLite beginTransactionNonExclusive() blocks database access

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a really long running transaction in background thread which...

- iterates through around batches of 400 records
- checks if it exists
- update if it exists, create new otherwise
- iterate through all of them again, to do some operation

and number of batches may vary.

The problem is: as long as the transaction is running, I cannot access database. I'm using a single instance of `SQLiteOpenHelper` to access database throughout application.

I've tried `yieldIfContendedSafely()` method, but it doesn't seem to work (or am I using it incorrectly?)

If I try to access database when the transaction is running, it does not throw any exception. It just sits there, like in a queue, and runs immediately when transaction ends.

PS: It is safe to access the database in this scenario, since transaction is running on one table, and I'm trying to read another table.

Comment: This is a [FAQ](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

Comment: I've read it already. I'm asking it in context of Android specifically.